# How to look for current running app in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build an android app in kotlin that can run in background and look for currently running app.
For example, let's say i opened YouTube in my phone and then app should automatically turn on night mode and when i close YouTube, app should turn off night mode.
Most off the answers here are in Java and outdated/depreciated like GET_TASKS permission.

Comment: They’re deprecated because for security reasons Android has become more and more strict about what your app is allowed to do. There is no new or better way. You just can’t do it anymore.

Comment: To expound on what @Tenfour04 said, think about it from the perspective of the other developer. Would you want some other app to be able to change the user experience of running your app or possibly do something malevolent while your app is running?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.